# Modify Liferay Database Tables

Tags: database, liferay

I want to remove some columns from table "User_" of Liferay Database (Lportal) as I don't want to store user's last login IP address. I know about Monitoring in Liferay but that can be turned off.

How can I stop Liferay from storing unnecessary details of user?

Answer (score 3):

Oh, this is a different level than usual. First of all: You *don't* write directly to the database.

Now for the next level: You *don't* change the structure of the database. While there might be less of an argument not to add columns, you definitely never ever ever ever remove columns.

That out of the way: If it's *just* the last login that you want to get rid of, you edit your portal-ext.properties file and configure it. Liferay's default is

```
# Set this to true to record last login information for a user.
#
users.update.last.login=true
```

naturally, you'll set it to false. However, beware of [LPS-51051](https://issues.liferay.com/browse/LPS-51051), you might need to patch for this issue if you run into the described behavior.